# I want vue-cli3 to output html with relative link

Tags: vue-cli-3

I not good at config webpack. So I am using vue-cli3 to create a project without change any congfigrations.

When I build the project, it create a /dist folder and index.html. The index.html use absolutely link such as `src=/js/app-legacy.69c62d1a.js` to link resources.

Fro some reasons, I want links are relative such as `src=./js/app-legacy.69c62d1a.js`.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `vue.config.js` file inside the project root folder to configure webpack.

If you want relative paths, it should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "./"
};
```

You can find more information in the [Configuration Reference](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/).